# What does XCode 4.2 story builder's "Defines Context" and "Provide Context" mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the Navigation Controller Attributes Inspector under View Controller section there are
the "Defines Context" and "Provide Context" check boxes.

[image]

I cant find any documentation on this features.
How to use it and what does it do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Defines Context" checkbox sets the `definesPresentationContext` property of the view controller.  The "Provides Context" checkbox sets the `providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle` property.

If you want to learn more about these properties, watch [WWDC 2011 Session 102: Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/102/).

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and open that link in Safari, Apple made it browser specific.

Comment: Don't waste your time, rewind to 42 minute of video to get explanation.

Comment: Or, if you're not into watching videos just to know what this is about, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445837/what-are-definespresentationcontext-and-providespresentationcontexttransitionsty