# UISearchController searchBar don't disappear when push viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a UISearchController inside ma `UIViewcontroller` that contains a `UITableView`, I do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

when I push a button in the navbar i do this:

```
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

all works fine, but when I push a `UIViewController` from a row in the `UITableView` results the `UISearchBar` stay there and display also on the content of the other view, how can i dismiss when I push a view and present when I go back to see the result of the `UITableView`?

thanks

EDIT:

this is the code of the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    DetailListController *detailList = [[DetailListController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailList animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` where you are pushing new view controller.

Comment: @Abhinav i have just add the code

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your view and detail view on storyboard ?

Comment: Try the code provided in documentation. It handles all the code properly

Comment: are using it on ios 8 or ios 9 ?

Comment: iOS 9, but is compatibile also with iOS 8

Comment: Do you have code related to UIStateRestoration that restores the status regarding the searchbar status ,search text, first responder etc ? @Piero

Comment: @Mr.T no i don't use any UIStateRestoration

Comment: I posted the code, you can try. If that doesnt work out for you, you can donwload the template from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/TableSearchwithUISearchController.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this standard way suggested by apple:

Declare the properties:

```
@interface APLMainTableViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;

// our secondary search results table view
@property (nonatomic, strong) APLResultsTableController *resultsTableController;

// for state restoration
@property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
@property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;

@end



    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _resultsTableController = [[APLResultsTableController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    // we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

    // Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
    // presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
    // hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
    //
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // restore the searchController's active state
    if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
        self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
        _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

        if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
            [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
            _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


#pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

// Called after the search controller's search bar has agreed to begin editing or when
// 'active' is set to YES.
// If you choose not to present the controller yourself or do not implement this method,
// a default presentation is performed on your behalf.
//
// Implement this method if the default presentation is not adequate for your purposes.
//
- (void)presentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

}

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is presented
}

- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something after the search controller is presented
}

- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something before the search controller is dismissed
}

- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    // do something after the search controller is dismissed
}
```

and here comes the interesting part: Use the below code to restore the status when you comeback from the detail view

```
#pragma mark - UIStateRestoration

// we restore several items for state restoration:
//  1) Search controller's active state,
//  2) search text,
//  3) first responder

NSString *const ViewControllerTitleKey = @"ViewControllerTitleKey";
NSString *const SearchControllerIsActiveKey = @"SearchControllerIsActiveKey";
NSString *const SearchBarTextKey = @"SearchBarTextKey";
NSString *const SearchBarIsFirstResponderKey = @"SearchBarIsFirstResponderKey";

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // encode the view state so it can be restored later

    // encode the title
    [coder encodeObject:self.title forKey:ViewControllerTitleKey];

    UISearchController *searchController = self.searchController;

    // encode the search controller's active state
    BOOL searchDisplayControllerIsActive = searchController.isActive;
    [coder encodeBool:searchDisplayControllerIsActive forKey:SearchControllerIsActiveKey];

    // encode the first responser status
    if (searchDisplayControllerIsActive) {
        [coder encodeBool:[searchController.searchBar isFirstResponder] forKey:SearchBarIsFirstResponderKey];
    }

    // encode the search bar text
    [coder encodeObject:searchController.searchBar.text forKey:SearchBarTextKey];
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // restore the title
    self.title = [coder decodeObjectForKey:ViewControllerTitleKey];

    // restore the active state:
    // we can't make the searchController active here since it's not part of the view
    // hierarchy yet, instead we do it in viewWillAppear
    //
    _searchControllerWasActive = [coder decodeBoolForKey:SearchControllerIsActiveKey];

    // restore the first responder status:
    // we can't make the searchController first responder here since it's not part of the view
    // hierarchy yet, instead we do it in viewWillAppear
    //
    _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = [coder decodeBoolForKey:SearchBarIsFirstResponderKey];

    // restore the text in the search field
    self.searchController.searchBar.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:SearchBarTextKey];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 11):

Put this code in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you don't do this, the search controller walks up the hierarchy to find a presentation context, if you don't do this it will be presented from the navigation controller, not your view controller.

Comment: This magic line also fixes some other UISearchController-related bugs. It can also be set in view controller settings via Interface Builder ("Defines Context" checkbox). See more about this tiny setting in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500398/2650588

Comment: In my particular setup I was able to get rid of all search controller bugs (iOS 10 and 11) with these 2 magic lines: `self.definesPresentationContext = true` and `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

Comment: in this case search bar isn't expanded at all, I can type to search something but I don't see any input text field

Answer (score 6):

You need to call this when you come back from `DetailListController` to your view controller (encapsulating in main thread for safety):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.searchController.active = NO;
});
```

You can also call this in `viewWillDisappear:` of your current view controller.

Comment: when i come back? and when i push the view i have do to nothing?

Comment: The OP is using UISearchController not UISearchDisplayController. You might edit your answer @Abhinav

Comment: searchdisplay is deprecated in ios 8

Comment: i don't think this is the right solution, i want the search bar, and then present it when i come back and the search is still active, if i set the active property to NO, i lost my search when i come back, i think the problem is in the self.definesPresentationContext, because if i set it to YES, the search bar appear and disappear with no problem, but it's presented in the middle of the uitableview not in the header

Comment: this fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

After trying to deal with the same problem for a few days, realized that the proper way of doing this is to have a navigation controller that contains everything in the search hierarchy

like this :

- Navigation 1 (no nav bar)
- (.... tab bar, anything else ...)
- Navigation 2 (has nav bar, this nav bar is replaced by the search bar
- Table controller

when you push details controller, you push it into navigation 1, showing its navigation bar at the same time.

This leaves search stack untouched and ready to work when you hit "back" on the detail page