# Remove search bar from UISearchController on push

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a search bar icon that calls this upon being pressed :

```
SearchTableViewController *searchView = [[SearchTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchTableViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCtlr = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchView];
UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:navCtlr];
[searchController setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
searchController.delegate = searchView;
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchView;
searchView.searchController = searchController;
searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
[self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Inside my SearchTableViewController.m file, I have a push segue that is successfully called:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 DetailTableViewController *seeAll = (DetailTableViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailTableViewController"];
 seeAll.query = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
 seeAll.title = @"Songs";
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:seeAll animated:YES];
```

However, i am not getting the expected behaviour ie.

Expected based on Apple Music's UISearchController :
Before Push:
[image: Before Push]

After Push:
[image: After Push]

And whats happening for me :

This is the same before and after push:
[image: Before Push]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a duplication question. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974723/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-dont-disappear-when-push-viewcontroller) may help.

You can download the UISearchController demo from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/TableSearchwithUISearchController.zip)

Comment: No its not a duplicate question.  That answer is for a filtering uiseaechcontroller with self being the results controller please read the question before answering

Comment: I mean that you can follow the demo, do not present a UISearchController but present another viewcontroller(i call it aVC) which hold a UISearchController property. when the result tableview be selected, push the detailVC into the aVC.navigationController.

Comment: OK well the demo does not do that and if I do that I will loose the aninations